# Configure version tag in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Each time I do an `eb deploy` AWS's EB service generates a random version number for me under "Running version".

Is there a way to tell EB how what you want your version tag to be? Like v1.2.3?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `eb deploy -l <version label>` to specify your desired label.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html